# Select Column Values as Comma Separated String in azure synapse sql server

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Here is my requirement

```
Data

1 Umesh usc@gmail.com
2 Umesh usc@yahoo.com
3 Mahesh msc@zyx.com

Out put
1 Umesh usc@gmail.com,usc@yahoo.com
2 Mahesh msc@zyx.com
```

FOR XML is working fine in SQL on prim sql server but same query is not working in Synapse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Synapse Analytics does not support `FOR XML` but it does support `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` as table functions.  You need `STRING_AGG` for your query.  A simple example, tested on a dedicated SQL pool:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    rowId           INT  PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED NOT ENFORCED,
    someName        VARCHAR(50),
    someEmail       VARCHAR(50)
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    HEAP
);

INSERT INTO #tmp ( rowId, someName, someEmail )
SELECT 1, 'Umesh', 'usc@gmail.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Umesh', 'usc@yahoo.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Mahesh', 'msc@zyx.com';


SELECT someName, STRING_AGG( someEmail, ',' ) result
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY someName
```

My results:

[image: results]

Comment: PERFECT! I;m glad MSFT thought ahead if they were going to remove a feature they would add it in another waY!

Comment: I always thought the xml trick for concatenating strings was a bit of a hack so I’m glad there’s a proper way of doing it now.  How about an upvote @Sauron??  : )

Comment: @wBob already did BOBBY!!